# How to create/ WPF Dependency Property in UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, user-controls

How to create/ WPF Dependency Property in UserControl?
Is it possible to create it through viewmodel?

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl
{   
    SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel(ForeColor);

    public SomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }

    public Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(ForeColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ForeColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForeColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ForeColor", typeof(Color), typeof(SomeView));
}
```

and then calling the control like below doesn't work.

```
 <local:SomeView ForeColorProperty="{Binding Foreground}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference it as "ForeColor", not "ForeColorProperty".

```
<local:SomeView ForeColor="{Binding Foreground}"/>
```

For the above binding to work, there has to be a public property "Foreground" of type "Color" in the control's current data context.

**Edit**

If you want to pass the value to the view model, then you need a two-way binding:

```
<local:SomeView ForeColor="{Binding Foreground,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: thanks, it helps. But how to pass it as a constructor parameter for the ViewModel? I have edited the question.

Comment: @user2330678 it looks like you want a two-way binding?

Comment: @user2330678 it's a bit nonsensical to bind the view's property to its view model, but then want to pass the value from the view to the viewmodel.  That sounds like a two-way binding, but it's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your edit didn't help. I am trying to pass Foreground color form the parent window (its xaml) calling usercontrol to usercontrol's viewmodel as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @user2330678 well, how do you expect to pass `ForeColor` *from the view to the viewmodel*, when the view gets it from viewmodel via a binding? You've got some circular logic going on there.

Comment: I am trying to pass ForColor from Window's xaml to Usercontrol's viewmodel.

Comment: @user2330678 and why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I am getting the foreground from somebody else's API, which I have to use. I need to pass that foreground value to the usercontrol's viewmodel.

Comment: @user2330678 And which API object exactly contains the "foreground" property that you need to use?

Comment: Its a business object. It would be passed as a Windows.Drawing.Color from the hosting Windows forms app to my WPF Prism app/UI.